# How do I center my document.write string?

Tags: javascript, background

Hello I am trying to find out how to center my document.write string. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

The reason it needs to be document.write is that it is part of my assignment.

Below is the code i am trying to Center and make bigger.

```
document.write (username + " " + job + " and the " + technology + " of Destiny" +
"<br><br>Set 3000 years in the future, a down-on-his-luck " + career + " teams up with a robot " + animal + " and a world-famous " + technology + 
" hacker to steal the last " + technology + " on Earth from the " + authority + " of the New World Government. <br>This " + 
(wholeHours + " Hour " + wholeMinutes + " Minutes ") + "long film stars Nick Cage as Thor " + job + 
", and Morgan Freeman as the voice of " + color + " " + animal + " " + getRndInteger(age,videogames));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `document.write`, write a tag to the document and have the [`text-align: center;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) property to center it.

```js
document.write('<h3 style="text-align: center;">test</h3>');
```